# Why am I getting an error message when trying to change the background-image?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website and I am trying to change the background image of the body but for some reason it is not working.

Error message: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND background-home-desktop.jpg:1`

Code:

```
body {
  background-image: url(assets/home/background-home-desktop.jpg);
  background-color: black;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

My files:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling it from the **CSS** folder. Then put '`../`' before assets.

Try it:

```
body {
  background-image: URL('../assets/home/background-home-desktop.jpg');
  background-color: black;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```